# Magento - Accessing values from an Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection object

Tags: php, arrays, magento, object

I am new to magento and php and I am trying to retrieve values from an object.

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

When I do a `print_r()` I am getting something like below

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection Object
(
    [_flatEnabled:protected] => Array
        (
            [1] => 
        )

    [_productWebsiteTable:protected] => sn_catalog_product_website
    [_productCategoryTable:protected] => sn_catalog_category_product
    [_addUrlRewrite:protected] => 1
    [_urlRewriteCategory:protected] => 3
    [_addMinimalPrice:protected] => 
    [_addFinalPrice:protected] => 
    [_allIdsCache:protected] => 
    [_addTaxPercents:protected] => 1
    [_productLimitationFilters:protected] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 3
            [category_is_anchor] => 1
            [store_id] => 1
            [use_price_index] => 1
            [customer_group_id] => 0
            [website_id] => 1
            [visibility] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )
)
```

And I need to get the category ID in this.
Can someone please help me

Comment: FYI: In Magento, collections are iterable resource objects which may contain a collection of data models. To learn about the containted items' data, you can `foreach($collection as $item)` and inside use `$item->debug()`.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to get the category from a product list is the long way around as a product list is part of a category. I assume you are doing this on category pages (otherwise you are dealing with more than one category, such as on a search page) in which case you can retrieve it more directly;

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$categoryId = $category->getId();

// to find out what other info is stored, temporarily use this
print_r($category->debug());
```

Answer (score 1):

you are dealing with collection that is a massive containing multiple collection items (objects) so to get data out of there you need to iterate over this first

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach($_productCollection as $product){

//display data that object contains
//print_r($product->getData());

//display category id's that product is associated with
//print_r($product->getCategoryIds());

}
```